# How to customize emmet for dynamic java script code generation like html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, emmet

I have installed and  customized emmet(zen coding) with support for java script snippets in snippets.json folder for sublime, so that i could expand abbreviations. it works and for expands properly from these definitions

```
"js": 
  {
      "abbreviations": {
        "em":  "emmet"
      },
      "snippets": {
      "forn": "for(i=0;i<${id};i++)\n{\n\t\n}",
      "for": "for (var ${class} = 0; i < ${id}; ${class}++) {\n\t|}"
      }
  }
```

**So far so good Now what i wanted is** when i use 
for>len/=N>  in input panel to embed some code inside the for loop.
i expect

```
for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
  len/=N
}
```

But  what ever i type it gets embedded in HTML tag 
following the for loop .

how do i mix snippets and user defined variables after the loop 
not inside the loop. 
**
similarly i want similar syntax (text*5+=cars) that  may expand to this kind of pattern

```
text += cars[0] + "<br>"; 
text += cars[1] + "<br>"; 
text += cars[2] + "<br>"; 
text += cars[3] + "<br>"; 
text += cars[4] + "<br>"; 
text += cars[5] + "<br>";
```

Comment: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/#variables

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thanks for answering. Actually i saw this doc page, but wanted something different, i have updated the question, please answer and share any examples that may help forming complex nested code instead of  html tags for pure java script with no html

Answer (score 0):

So such things you have to write custom abbreviation postprocessor that can find abbreviation in parsed tree and replace it with custom snippet.

take a look at [Lorem Ipsum generator](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/generator/lorem.js). It takes a parsed abbreviation tree, traverses it finds nodes that matched some criteria. These nodes then replaced with custom snippets.

Your code might look something like this:

```
(function() {
    function resolve(tree) {
        tree.children.forEach(function(node) {
            if (/^my-prefix/.test(node.name())) {
                // do something
                node._name = ''; // empty name
                node.content = 'add some cusom content';
            }

            // walk recursively
            resolve(node);
        });
    }

    // register post-processor
    emmet.require('parser/abbreviation').addPostprocessor(resolve)
})();
```

You can put this file into your extensions dir.

PS: note that both `/` and `=` characters are illegal for Emmet abbreviations. Valid abbreviation name must conform [this regexp](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/parser/abbreviation.js#L36).